# Using Phonegap API Prompt to replace javascript Prompt

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am buidling an app using Phonegap I am using a javascript prompt for inputting category names, which works fine

```
    var newcat=prompt("ADD CATEGORY","");
```

I want to replace it with the Phonegap API prompt, which I thought would be

```
    var newcat=navigator.notification.prompt('', null,'ADD CATEGORY', ['Ok','Exit'],  '');
```

However this doesn't work on the ipad - the prompt appears, however no category name is getting inputted.

Furthermore I get 'default text' in the input box (I'd like it to be empty) and 'Prompt Message' underneath the 'ADD CATEGORY' title (I'd also like this to be empty)

Update -  I tried the following using a callback function which doesn't work either

```
    function onPrompt(results) {
    var newcat=results.input1;
    }
    navigator.notification.prompt(' ', onPrompt,'ADD CATEGORY', ['Ok','Exit'],  ' ');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
window.navigator.notification.prompt(
    new String(), // message
    function(answer) {
        if (answer.buttonIndex === 1) {
            // Ok
            var newcat = answer.input1;
            transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO cat (Name) VALUES (?)", [newcat]);
        }
        else {
            // Exit
        }
    }, // callback
    "ADD CATEGORY", //title
    ["Ok", "Exit"], // button titles
    new String() // defaultText
);
```

Comment: thanks Jonas wont the variable 'newcat' only be available within the function 'answer'? I need to pass the newcat variable to the function which follows the prompt    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO cat(Name) VALUES (?)',[newcat],

Comment: will this work if in the form -  var newcat=navigator.notification.prompt...etc

Comment: No it won't. window.navigator.notification.prompt will call the native UIAlertView and your Javascript code will just go on. Everything you want to do with the users input you have to do in the callback function.